# How to specify more than one port on Azure endpoint for SMTP?

Tags: azure, endpoint

what is the right way to add ports in Azure endpoint,

I'm trying to add ports 25, 465 and 587 to SMTP

Should I just create 3 entries? one for each port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 entries, 1 per each TCP port that you want to expose .

```
TCP/25  - TCP/25
TCP/465 - TCP/465
TCP/587 - TCP/587
```